# How many bit strings of length 20 have exactly five $1$’s and do not contain $11111$ as a substring?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Recall that a bit string is a string composed of characters $0$ and $1$.

Can someone explain how the answer is:

${20\choose5} - 16$?

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Also: titles should be a description of the question, not simply the first sentence of the background.

Comment: 5 positions out of 20 for the ones; but not the sequences that are $k$ zeroes ($0 \le k \le 15$), five ones, and $10 - 5 - k$ zeroes. There are $16$ such sequences.

Answer (score 2):

For a bit string length 20 with exactly 5 1's, it must also have exactly 15 0's. In other words, we need to arrange 5 1's and 15 0's in a line. Thus, the number of these bit strings is

$$\frac{20!}{5!\cdot15!} = \binom{20}{5}$$

Sixteen of these strings contain the substring 11111 (1111100...00, 01111100...0..etc.) - we can place the start of the substring 11111 in 16 different places because it can start anywhere from the 1st to the 16th digit in the string.

Thus, the total number of such strings is $\binom{20}{5}-16$

Comment: How did you know 16 of the strings contain the substring 11111?

Comment: @Stuy I believe I explained it in my answer, feel free to ask further questions

Comment: @Stuy They are uniquely determined by the startung position of the 11111 block

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. I thought it was 16 because 2^5 is 16.

Comment: $2^{4}=16$. Also we are not using powers of 2 because we have already chosen how many 1s and 0's there are (5 and 15). Have another look at the part that says 'Sixteen of these strings contain the substring 11111' for examples of possible strings