# How many bit strings of length $20$ have exactly two 1’s and do not contain 11 as a substring?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to solve this. I know there are $2^{20}$ strings.

Comment: How many ways to place exactly two 1s are there? How many of these have the two 1s next to each other?

Comment: Alternatively, start with strings of length 19 that have exactly two ones, and insert an additional zero between the ones.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3327989/27542

Answer (score 2):

If the first $1$ is in the first position, then the second $1$ can be in positions 3 to 20 (18 choices). If the first $1$ is in position 2, then the second is in 4 to 20 (17 choices). And so on. When the first $1$ is in position 18, the second must be in position 20 (1 choice). So the answer is $$18+17+...+2+1=\frac{18\cdot 19}{2}=171$$

Answer (score 2):

Could the following work?

> Since the string is entirely determined by which bits are on, there are ${20 \choose 2}$ ways of picking the two bits that'll have value $1$ and from that number we have to substract the cases where the bits are adjacent, i.e. in 19 of the total cases. So the number of strings with 2 non-adjacent 1's is ${20 \choose 2}-19=\frac{20!}{18!2!}-19=19*10-19=19*9=171$